# Triangle with two sides given find the greatest area if the area is prime number

Tags: area

A triangle has two sides of lengths 4 centimeters
and 6 centimeters. Its area is n square
centimeters, where n is a prime number. What
is the greatest possible value of n?
(A) 11
(B) 12
(C) 19
(D) 23
(E) 24

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Area of a triangle $A = \left|\frac{1}{2}ab\sin\theta\right|$
   where $a, b$ are the lengths of two sides and $\theta$ is the angle between them.
2. $|\sin\theta| \le 1$
3. (B) is not a prime number